# Coarse geometry of minimal surfaces in non-positively curved manifolds

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $X$ be a simply-connected Riemannian manifold of non-positive curvature and $S\subset X$ be a complete minimal surface.

(You can basically image $X$ as a ball and $S$ as an embedded disk whose boundary is a circle in $\partial X$.)

I want to compare the two metrics (or distances) on $S$: the first, $d_1$, is the distance given by the induced Riemannian metric; while the second, $d_2$, is the direct restriction of the distance of $X$.

**Question:** In general, are $d_1$ and $d_2$ quasi-isometric?

Comment: No, even in hyperbolic 3-space, a minimal surface can be exponentially distorted.

Comment: Is there any reference on that ? What about minimal surfaces in a quasi-Fuchsian 3-manifold, lifted to $\mathbb{H}^3$?

Comment: For the universal cover of a quasifuchsian surface, this will be true. But for a minimal surface realizing the fiber of a fibration, its universal cover will not embed quasi-isometrically.

Comment: @Ian Actually I only need the result for incompressible minimal surfaces in quasi-Fuchsian manifolds. How to see that ?

Comment: There's a convex core for the fundamental group of a quasifuchsian surface, whose universal cover is quasi-isometric to the surface (and in particular a minimal surface representative).